# how to send dynamically created object's pointer to self(this) as a signal parameter

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, signals-slots

I have many dynamically created qml objects which have a single explicitly declared parent. I want to connect every signal of each object to their parent's method and I need to differentiate which object sent the signal. I want to send object pointer as signal parameter. Is this possible? If it's not how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Mitch Try what exactly? I don't know how to do it that's what I am asking.

Comment: I don't think there is a this pointer as this is not c++. From what I looked there isn't even  a way to send this with qt's c++ signals but I haven't tried

Comment: I think the closest analogue of `sender()` from C++ is to send `objectName`. Then you can provide from C++ some function to get pointer to the object by `objectName`. Of course you have to assign a unique name to each item.

Comment: Clearly you have written some code that you're not showing us. So rather than asking a poorly phrased question with no minimal example code and then rudely dismissing the answers, why don't you put some effort into your question.

Comment: @Mitch  Well its complicated code so it takes time to make  it suitable for question. But in this I thought I was asking a clear specific feature to fix my case. I didn’t say your answer was useless I would have downvoted it if I thought so. I didn’t want to offend you in any way. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so clear what do you want to achieve, I just guess I got it right.
So, you can use child item id which is an analog of *this*.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    title: "test"
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: root
        function itemClicked(item, serial)
        {
            console.log("Item (" + item + ") with serial: " + serial + " was clicked");
        }
        Repeater {
            model: 5
            delegate: Test {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                onPressed1: root.itemClicked(sender, serial)
                Connections {
                    onPressed2: root.itemClicked(target, serial);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you create your items dynamically, using `Qt.createComponent`, just replace `Repeater` with the following code:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    for(var i = 0;i < 5;i ++)
    {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Test.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready)
        {
            var obj = component.createObject(root);
            obj.color = Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
            obj.width = 50;
            obj.height = 50;
            obj.pressed1.connect(root.itemClicked);
            obj.pressed2.connect(function(serial){
                root.itemClicked(obj, serial);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    id: item
    signal pressed1(Item sender, int serial)
    signal pressed2(int serial)
    property int serial: Math.round(Math.random() * 9999)
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            item.pressed1(item, item.serial);
            item.pressed2(item.serial);
        }
    }
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text:serial
    }
}
```

The item Test proposes `onPressed` signal with an parameter. Use `pressed1` if you can modify your item and add it. Or use `pressed2` without changing the item. Finally the root item receives the signal with item reference and the parameter.

Comment: Your solution seems to work but you are creating Test objects declaratively. That is not what I meant by dynamic objects. I have to create my objects with Qt.createComponent and createObject functions on demand. So I only have a var object reference in javascript after the object is created. To my knowledge the only way to connect signals is to use connect method on the signal and I don't think you can achieve your "root.itemClicked(sender, serial)" with that. I will accept your answer as its my fault not to specify what is dynamic object. I managed to solve my case in another way. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't point the way you create items so I just taked `Repeater` as an example. But you can use `Qt.createComponent` in the same way. See my updated answer.